# Polynomials and Trig

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

**Question:**

The equation $x^{2}-x+1=0$ has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Show that $\alpha ^{n}+\beta ^{n}=2\cos\frac{n\pi }{3}$ for $n=1, 2, 3...$

**Attempt:**

$x^{2}=x-1 \Rightarrow x^{n}=x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}$ for $n=3, 4, 5...$

$\therefore \alpha^{n}=\alpha^{n-1}-\alpha^{n-2}$

$\therefore \alpha ^{n}+\beta ^{n}=\alpha ^{n-1}+\beta ^{n-1}-\alpha ^{n-2}-\beta ^{n-2}$

I don't see how I could link this with cosine.

Could you please go beyond answering the question and proving that $\alpha ^{n}+\beta ^{n}=2\cos\frac{n\pi }{3}$ and explain the question to me why this relation between the roots and trig happen?

The question can probably be done by induction but is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know De Moivre's formula?

Comment: Yes I do, but don't we use $cis$ in DMT?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula to find the roots, express them in polar form to get that they are $\cos \tfrac{\pi}{3} \pm i \sin \tfrac{\pi}{3}$, then apply De Moivre.

Comment: Makes sense. I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and the roots of $x^3+1=0$ lie on the unit circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$x^2-x+1=0\implies x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-3}}2=\begin{cases}\frac{1-\sqrt3\,i}2=e^{-\frac{2\pi i}3}=\text{cis}\left(-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\{}\\\frac{1+\sqrt3\,i}2=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}=\text{cis}\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)\end{cases}$$

Note thus that

$$x_1=\overline{x_2}=x_2^{-1}\implies x_1+x_2=2\text{Re}\,(x_1)=2\cos\frac{2\pi}3\implies x_1^n+x_2^n=\;\ldots\ldots$$